# Prevent session end when webroot changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

Our intranet has a custom membership system (not asp membership) which puts values in the session information to identify users. As the intranet is constantly evolving, I often have to publish changes to the live server several times every day. Each time I do, the users who are logged in's sessions end and they have to log in again. This causes various issues which I won't bore anybody with here.

My question - is there anyway to prevent this, or do I just have to live with it? Have spent the last 3 hours Goggling and can find no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a different Session Mode; You are using "InProc", which means the session is stored in the same application space as your application.  You can use "StateServer" or "SQLServer", however these will likely require application changes (and additional setup; StateServer will require a separate service to be running on the IIS Server and SQLServer will require a database to store information in).  Everything that you store in the Session will need to be serializable.

[Here is the information on MSDN regarding Session Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Comment: Thanks!! That makes sense. Can't believe 1: I couldn't find that out myself and 2: I wrote "Goggling". I hate it when people do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Sql Server session state storage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about keeping your server up 24x7 without causing any disruption to users (loss of session/ system downtime, etc), then it involves the following steps:

1. You should configure your application to store your sessions in DB
2. You need to set up more than one app server as fail-over strategy
3. To route requests to one of these servers dynamically, you'll need a load balancer
4. Now, when you want to deploy the next version of release live to app. servers say S1 and S2, follow the steps below:
   [4.1.] Change your load balancer configuration for it to not route requests to S1.
   [4.2.] Deploy the apps to S1
   [4.3.] Change your load balancer configuration for it include S1 and exclude S2 this time. (With this all subsequent requests shall hit S1 getting the session info. from the common DB where S1 and S2 are connected)
   [4.4.] Repeat the above steps as required.

Most important of all try to always test the above steps in your staging environment before doing it first on live/production boxes.

Good luck!